# How to Stop a fluid domain?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have a fluid sim and it keeps on going for 20 frames and them becomes a cube. How do I stop this sim after 8 frames?(In a beginner!!)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to domain settings under cache -> reduce the end frame[image]

Comment: If you found it useful pls hit the tick mark beside the answer to help others facing the same issue